# Is there a way around bug JDK-8004476 so XSLT extensions work over webstart prior to Java 8?

Tags: java, xslt, java-web-start, xslt-extension

Bug [JDK-8004476](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8004476) is fixed in Java 8, but I'm stuck in a Java 6/7 environment.  My application, which launches through webstart using jnlp, includes an XSL transform and uses an extension namespace to link static methods.  Launched locally, it works perfectly but per the bug, launch it via webstart and it can't find the methods.

Are there any known work arounds?